# Formatting C++ Header Files in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper

Is there any extension out there or option to format c++ header files in specific way?

Say we have this header file:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    int m_iMember1;
    std::string m_sMember2;
    std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>> m_someLongMember;

protected:
    int m_iMember3;

private:
    std::string m_sMember4;

public:
    void Function1();
    std::string Function2();

    SomeClass() = default;

protected:
    std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>> Function3();

private:
    bool IsThereAnyWayOfDoingThis;

};
```

And the way I want the header to be:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    int                                         m_iMember1;
    std::string                                 m_sMember2;
    std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>>     m_someLongMember;

protected:
    int                                         m_iMember3;

private:
    std::string                                 m_sMember4;

public:
    void                                        Function1();
    std::string                                 Function2();

    SomeClass() = default;

protected:
    std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>>     Function3();

private:
    bool                                        IsThereAnyWayOfDoingThis;

};
```

I'm using resharper plugin and with resharper I can `CTRL + ENTER` and choose `Format Selection`.
Visual Studio also have build in code formatting. But is there a way configuring it's behavior? Or anyone aware of any extension to do this for us?
Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

With ReSharper, you can always check what formatting preferences affect a block of code. Just select a code snippet, hit `Alt+Enter`, and choose `Format Selection -> Configure...`. ReSharper will show a dialog where you can change formatting options and instantly see how this affects the formatting style.

In this case you need to enable `Indentation and Alignment | Align Similar Code In Columns | Declaration names`. It won't work however across accessibility specifiers. Please also note that it's a relatively new feature, available in ReSharper 2017.3 and later.